# I cant change the input value react v0.14

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using react-table also react v0.14. My question is when i click the details button ı take the data and pass the input value.But when open the details page ı want to update name and email but ı couldn't ı cant write anything is pretended like a disabled input what I have to do ?

[image: React-Table-Page]

[image: Edit Page]

```
    this.state = {
          
          showAdminEdit : false,
          test : {}
    };

showAdminEdit = (props) =>{
    this.test = props.original
    console.log(this.test)
    // e.preventDefault();
    
    this.setState({
      showAdminEdit: true
    });
  }

 render() {

 return (
            <section className="admin_create">
<Paper className="admin_paper" >
  <CardContent> 
   
  <form>

  <div className="form__group field">
    <input type="input" className="form__field" placeholder="Name" name="name" id="name" value={this.test.name}  />
    <label htmlFor="name" className="form__label">Name</label>
</div>
<div className="form__group field">
    <input type="input" className="form__field" placeholder="Name" name="name" id="name" value={this.test.mail}  />
    <label htmlFor="name" className="form__label">E-mail</label>
</div>

<div className="parent2">
<div className="div7">
<button onClick={this.createAdmin}>Save</button>
</div>
<div className="div8">
<button onClick={this.createCancel}>Back</button>
</div>
</div>

  </form>
```

Comment: const data = [
      {
        name: 'Jack' ,
        sicilno: 1423157,
        mail: 'Jack1@gmail.com'
      },
      {
        name: 'Brad' ,
        sicilno: 3453157,
        mail: 'brad1@gmail.com'
      },
      {
        name: 'stefan',
        sicilno: 5353157,
        mail: 'stefan1@gmail.com'
      },
      {
        name: 'cole',
        sicilno: 7253157,
        mail: 'cole1@gmail.com'
      }
    ];

Comment: const columns = [
      {
        Header: 'Name',
        accessor: 'name' 
      },
      {
        Header: 'StaffId',
        accessor: 'sicilno',
        Cell: (props) => <span className="number">{props.value}</span> 
      },
      {
        id: 'mail', 
        Header: 'Email',
        accessor: 'mail'
      },
      {
        id: 'Ekleme', 
        Header: 'Edit',
        Cell: props => <button className="showdetailcss" onClick={() => this.showAdminEdit(props)}>Details</button>
      }
    ];

Comment: <ReactTable
        data={data}
        columns={columns}
        // filterable="true"
        defaultPageSize="10"
      />

Answer (score 0):

You are unable to change the input fields because you are missing change event handler.

Create `name`, `email` in local state.

```js
constructor(props) {
  super(props)
  this.state = {
    name: '',
    email: ''
  }
}
```

Event handlers here:

```
<input
  type="input"
  className="form__field"
  placeholder="Name"
  name="name"
  id="name"
  value={this.state.name}
  onChange={e => this.setState({ name: e.target.value})}
/>
<input
  type="input"
  className="form__field"
  placeholder="email"
  name="email"
  id="email"
  value={this.state.email}
  onChange={e => this.setState({ email: e.target.value })}
/>
```